# QGraphicsView not showing image

Tags: c++, qt

I have a graphicsView in the UI, and I used this code to set an image from the Resources but doesn't work:

-In the header file:

```
QGraphicsScene *scene;
```

-In the cpp file:

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene();
scene->addPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/alert.png"));
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

What's wrong in the code?

Comment: Are u sure about the address? Nothing else is wrong.

Comment: I just found the mistake. In case anyone is having the same problem, it is infact the address. It should be ":/images/image/alert.png" Thank you :)